# .Net Core Danish localization

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, localization

I am working on an application that implements .net core localization. English and French are working fine but when trying to add a danish language it doesn't work.

I have 3 resource file for localization.

```
Viewmodel.en-GB.resx
Viewmodel.fr.resx
Viewmodel.da.resx
```

English and French are both working but the danish language is not working.

Comment: Can you expand on "not working"? Also, Danish (in Denmark) is typically [da-DK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ee825488(v=cs.20).aspx) - not sure if that's relevant.

Comment: I tried changing the resource file extension name to da-DK but still not working.

Comment: Yes, but what do you mean by "not working"? Does it give the wrong output? Does it crash?

Comment: It doesn't crash but it gives wrong output.

Comment: @RamppyDumppy - What about the output is "wrong"? Is it the wrong language? Is it the default language? Please explain the behavior you are seeing.

Comment: yes, its' using the default language. For example in chrome if I set the language to danish it will translate to english instead of danish

Comment: There is a good introduction to ASP.NET Core Localization [here](https://andrewlock.net/adding-localisation-to-an-asp-net-core-application/). Look at the section about RequestLocalizationMiddleware. Maybe using the example code in ConfigureServices and specifying da in the selection of SupportedCultures would fix the problem.